# How to create views with soft persistence?

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I need to create a view, using MySQL.

But the problem is the view recalculates all of the data when we try to get some data from it. And for complex views, with several calculus, this is a problem.

How could I maintain persistence for a couple of hours (for example, 6)?

Is there way to avoid to create a real table and sync it?

Answer (score 0):

A view always displays the most recent data, since it is just a view of actual tables, and has no ability to hold any data for itself.

I would solve this by creating a concrete table instead of a view, with all required data, and update this periodically with some type of cronjob.